# Should I cache the Carrierwave url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

My webhost is Heroku, which does not allow files to be saved to the local file system. Therefore, I am using Carrierwave to store my files onto Amazon S3.

In the console, I notice when I do:

```
Photo.last.attachment.url
```

It returns:

```
 => "https://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/1/photos/7/foo.jpg"
```

As expected. However, this process (of returning the value) in the console takes up 2-3 seconds. My guess is that it it trying to access S3. Even worst, when I load a web page with several photos, it takes quite a while to load.

Someone mentioned that because I am remotely storing my files via S3, I should cache the result from "**Photo.last.attachment.url**".

This means, in my db I would need to have two columns:

:attachment and :attachment_url

:attachment would be for the Carrierwave uploader object and :attachment_url would be the link to the S3 file directly.

Is this what I should be doing? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in a recent version of Carrierwave.  Better not to cache, URL creation is cheap.   It was a behavior of Fog to check for the file when creating the URL. Now the behavior is to simply give the link.  You can see this discussion:
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/289 and
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/261

Comment: Thanks for pointing this bug out and glad the devs of the gem managed to figure this issue. Much appreciated!

Comment: Although in this case it's better to not cache, it's wrong to say the URL creation IS cheap. In complex URL scenarios (displaying hierarchy of data) URL generation can be expensive, and thus caching would be recommended.

Comment: +1 for the clue-in.  I missed when this happened. I'll probably stick to caching but it's nice to know you no longer must (or face Fog querying s3 for every url on the page).

Answer (score 0):

I would do the caching. We have done a similar approach using Paperclip.

Alternatively you could be caching the views (partials) where the URLS are being used.